# python and opencv error

Tags: python, opencv

I am using a Mac OS X (snow leopard) and tried to install opencv with python bindings but i get the following error when I try to import the cv module:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv.py", line 3, in <module>
    from cv2.cv import *
ImportError: dlopen(/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv2.so, 2): Symbol not found: _av_alloc_format_context
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/libopencv_highgui.2.4.dylib
  Expected in: /opt/local/lib/libavformat.dylib
 in /usr/local/lib/libopencv_highgui.2.4.dylib
```

I added the following path: `export PYTHONPATH=/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH` to my `~/.profile`

Does anyone know how I can fix it?

Answer (score 1):

From the paths in your traceback, you appear to be trying to use a MacPorts-installed Python 2.7 with your own `opencv`.  Don't mix and match.  MacPorts already has an [`opencv` port](http://www.macports.org/ports.php?by=name&substr=opencv) with Python bindings; use it.  First, remove the `opencv` you installed to `/usr/local`.  Then install the MacPorts version with:

```
sudo port selfupdate
sudo port -u install opencv +python27
```